How to print dataLayer created by events in Shopify's Customer events?
I use Shopify's Customer Events to track eCommerce. However, I encounter a problem when I cannot see dataLayer as it is when certain events from the Customer Events trigger, so I don't know what DataLayer variables to create.
Is there a command that I can type in Shopify Customer Events that will print the dataLayer as it is? console.log on events set in Customer Events does not show dataLayer structure.

have you tried just console.logging the window?.dataLayer?
